# Proving that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}<20$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, problem-solving, radicals

How do I prove that:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}<20$$

Do I use induction?

Comment: Do you know some integral calculus?

Comment: What is integral calculus? Is it just integration?

Comment: compare to $\int x^{-1/2}$

Comment: Consequence from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394103/show-that-1-sqrt1-1-sqrt2-1-sqrtn-leq-2-sqrtn-1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove the inequality $2\sqrt{n + 1} − 2 \le 1 +\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}+\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}+ \dots +\frac 1 {\sqrt n} \le 2\sqrt n − 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995110/how-to-prove-the-inequality-2-sqrtn-1-%e2%88%92-2-le-1-frac-1-sqrt-2-frac-1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prove the following claim using induction on $n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{k}} < 2 \sqrt{n}$$

In the induction, you will essentially need to show that
$$2\sqrt{n} +\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} < 2 \sqrt{n+1} \tag{$\star$}$$

To prove $(\star)$, note that
$$\sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n+1} \implies \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1} <2 \sqrt{n+1} \implies \dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} < \dfrac2{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}$$
Multiplying and divding the right hand side by $(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$, we get
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}} < \dfrac2{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}} = 2({\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}})$$
which gives us  $(\star)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can use integral:

$$\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } +\dots +\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 100 }  } <\int _{ 0 }^{ 100 }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x }  }  } dx=20$$

You can imagine approximating the integral with rectangles of side $\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  }$ and $1$, will give less area than the integral because of the behaviour of the curve.

Comment: Your integral must run from $0$ to $100$ and not from $1$ to $100$. In fact, $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}} \approx 18.589 > 18$$