# Prove inequalities $2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + 1/\sqrt{2} + 1/\sqrt{3} + .... + 1/\sqrt{n}\leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove that for any positive integer $n$,
$$
2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + 1/\sqrt{2} + 1/\sqrt{3} + .... + 1/\sqrt{n}\leq 2\sqrt{n}-1
$$

the middle part can be expressed as a sum. of $1/\sqrt{x}$ from 1 to $n$, which leads to a $Hn^{0.5}$. Im not sure how that helps.

I tried differentiating both end functions and found they are both increasing.. But it doesn't seem to help much... help pls

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: @SimonS mathematical induction?

Comment: Yes, mathematical induction

Comment: SEE here; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002337/prove-that-for-any-positive-integer-n-2-sqrtn1-2-le-1-frac1-sqrt2/1002342#1002342

Comment: Instead of induction? Can i form a riemann sum with the middle portion. then deduce the f(x). use left and right rule to come up with inequality? since from the left the value will always be smaller than from the right

Comment: Standard comparisons with Riemann integrals of the decreasing function $x\mapsto1/\sqrt{x}$ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$

We prove this by proving the following statements:

1. $2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$
2. $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$

---

**Proof of (1) by Induction:**

$\\ \\$

*Base case:* Notice that $2\sqrt{1+1} - 2 \leq 1$.

$\\ \\$

*Inductive step:* Suppose $2\sqrt{k+1}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Then, $2\sqrt{k+1}-2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Thus, to show that $2\sqrt{k+2}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$, we can simply show that $2\sqrt{k+2}-2 \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}-2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

\begin{align}
                    & 2\sqrt{k+2}-2 \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}-2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 2\sqrt{k^2+3k+2} - 2\sqrt{k+1} \leq 2k + 2 -2\sqrt{k+1} + 1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 2\sqrt{k^2+3k+2} \leq 2k+3 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 4k^2+12k+8 \leq 4k^2+12k+9 \quad \text{as} \quad 2\sqrt{k^2+3k+2},2k+3 > 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 8 \leq 9 \quad \text{which is true}
\end{align}

Thus, (1) is proven.

---

**Proof of (2) by Induction:**
$\\ \\$

*Base case:* Notice that $1 \leq 2\sqrt{1}-1$.

$\\ \\$

*Inductive step:* Suppose $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 2\sqrt{k}-1$.

Then $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k}-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Thus to show that $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}-1$, we can simply show that $2\sqrt{k}-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}-1$.

\begin{align}
                    & 2\sqrt{k}-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}-1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k+1} \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 2\sqrt{k^2+k} + 1 \leq 2k+2 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 2\sqrt{k^2+k} \leq 2k+1 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 4k^2+4k \leq 4k^2+4k+1 \quad \text{as} \quad 2\sqrt{k^2+k},2k+1 > 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 0 \leq 1 \quad \text{which is true}
\end{align}

Thus, (2) is proven.

---

We now see that $2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$ are both true for all positive integers $n$. Thus, we conclude that $2\sqrt{n+1}-2 \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Thanks for a clear picture!! but how come u can sub the k assumption into k+1? i'm confused with the inequalities

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $2\sqrt{k+1} - 2\sqrt{k}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{k}} < \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} = 2\sqrt{k} - 2\sqrt{k-1}$. Now let $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$, and add up.

Comment: how is it that you can just add the term sqrt(k) and sqrt(k-1) without changing the equation?