# Inequality proof by induction, what to do next in the step

Tags: induction

I have to prove that for $n = 1, 2...$ it holds: $2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Base: For $n = 1$ holds, because $2\sqrt{2}-2 < 1$

Step: assume holds for $n_0$.

$2\sqrt{n+2} - 2 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}$. But I do not know what to do next? How this can be proved?

Comment: Almost the same problem was posted recently. Check out my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003521/prove-inequalities-2-sqrtn1-2-leq-1-1-sqrt2-1-sqrt3-1-s/1003696?noredirect=1#comment2052363_1003696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume it holds for $n$, i.e.
$$ 2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}. $$
You now want to prove that it holds for $n+1$, i.e.
$$ 2\sqrt{n+2} - 2 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}. $$
Subtracting the first inequality from the second, you only have to show that
$$ 2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}. $$
Rearrangement yields
$$ \frac{\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+1}} - 1 < \frac{1}{2}, $$
so
$$ \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{3}{2}. $$
Squaring both sides gives us
$$ \frac{n+2}{n+1} < \frac{9}{4}, $$
after which cross multiplication results in
$$ 4n+8 < 9n+9, $$
which is obvious for all $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For induction step, it's enough to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})$.
$$2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{2}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: It's not extremely easy to see that $$2\left(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}},$$ though.

Comment: $a^2 -b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ ? Not that hard either :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}+2\sqrt{n+1}-2&=\frac{1+2(n+1)}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+12n+9}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\\
&>\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+12n+8}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{n^2+3n+2}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{(n+2)(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\\
&=2\sqrt{n+2}-2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove this first: x>0, : $ 2*\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} > 2*\sqrt{x+1} $

This is true iif : $ (2*\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2 > (2*\sqrt{x+1})^2 $

You get : $ 2*\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} > 2*\sqrt{x+1} $ <=> $ 4x + \frac{1}{x} +4 > 4*(x+1) $ <=> $ \frac{1}{x} > 0 $ which is true, so the inequality is true as well :) .

Now for the induction step :

$ 2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $

=> $2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

But we have from the first part of the answer : $2*\sqrt{n+1} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} -2 > 2*\sqrt{n+1+1} -2 = 2*\sqrt{n+2} -2$

Hence you get: $ 2*\sqrt{n+2} -2 < 2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ Induction holds :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the claim is true for $n=1$ it suffices to prove that at each step the increment on the left hand side is smaller than on the right hand side. But
$$2\bigl(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}\bigr)={2\over\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}<{1\over\sqrt{n+1}}\ .$$