# Show that $1/\sqrt{1} + 1/\sqrt{2} + ... + 1/\sqrt{n} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

Show that $1/\sqrt{1} + 1/\sqrt{2} + ... + 1/\sqrt{n} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1$ for $n\geq 1$

I attempted the problem but I get stuck trying to show that if the statment is true for some $k\geq1$ then $k+1$ is also true.

My attempt: Base case $n=1$ is true by inspection

Now assume the statement is true for some $k\geq1$. Then $1/\sqrt{1} + 1/\sqrt{2} + ... + 1/\sqrt{n} +1\sqrt{n+1} \leq 2\sqrt{n}-1 + 1/\sqrt{n+1}$ but I am not sure how to show the rest.

Comment: Related questions: [How to prove the inequality $2\sqrt{n + 1} − 2 \le 1 +\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}+\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}+ \dots +\frac 1 {\sqrt n} \le 2\sqrt n − 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995110/how-to-prove-the-inequality-2-sqrtn-1-%E2%88%92-2-le-1-frac-1-sqrt-2-frac-1), [Proving that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}<20$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395979/proving-that-frac1-sqrt1-frac1-sqrt2-dots-frac1-sqrt1002).

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt{k}-2\sqrt{k-1}$. You let $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$, and add the inequalities up.

Answer (score 1):

If the proposition holds true for $n=m$

$$\sum_{r=1}^m\dfrac1{\sqrt r}\le2\sqrt m-1$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^{m+1}\dfrac1{\sqrt r}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}}+\sum_{r=1}^m\dfrac1{\sqrt r}\le\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}}+2\sqrt m-1$$

It if sufficient to show  $$\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}}+2\sqrt m-1\le2\sqrt{m+1}-1$$

$$\iff\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}}\le2[\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt m]=\dfrac2{\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt m}$$

$$\iff \sqrt{m+1}\ge\sqrt m$$ which is true

Comment: How does the last line follow?

Comment: @dan,  
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}}\le\dfrac2{\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt m}\iff2\sqrt{m+1}\ge\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt m\iff?$$

Answer (score 1):

Without induction you could use this inequality

$$\frac1{\sqrt k}\le2(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})$$
and then you telescope. Notice also that the same inequality is useful for your attempt.